# Can anyone explain me this code

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef EIGHT_BIT
#define THIRTYTWO_BIT // default 32 bit
#endif

#ifdef THIRTYTWO_BIT
#define WORD unsigned long
#define WORDLENGTH 4

#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(__GNUC__)
#define WORD64  unsigned __int64
#else
#define WORD64  unsigned long long
#endif

// THIRTYTWO_BIT
#endif


#ifdef EIGHT_BIT

#define WORD unsigned short
#define WORDLENGTH 4

// EIGHT_BIT
#endif
```

Comment: actually it does. Include this code in some source code where you use 'WORD' somewhere.

Comment: @tobias langner, what i meant is that code doesn't have any executable statement. :)

Comment: This code is almost nonsense so forget it and don't use it (or fix it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note about this code is that none of it will actually be compiled into C. Every line that isn't whitespace or a comment starts with a pound sign (`#`), meaning they are preprocessor directives. A preprocessor directive alters the code before it even makes it to the compiler. For more information of preprocessor directives, see [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).

Now that we know that much, let's look through the code:

---

```
#ifndef EIGHT_BIT
#define THIRTYTWO_BIT // default 32 bit
#endif
```

If the macro `EIGHT_BIT` is not defined, define another macro called `THIRTYTWO_BIT`. This is most likely referring to the number of bits in a word on a processor. This code intends to be cross-platform, meaning that it can run on a number of processors. The snippet you posted pertains to managing different word widths.

---

```
#ifdef THIRTYTWO_BIT
#define WORD unsigned long
#define WORDLENGTH 4
```

If the macro `THIRTYTWO_BIT` is defined, then define a `WORD` to be an `unsigned long`, which has a `WORDLENGTH` of 4 (presumably bytes). Note that this statement isn't necessarily true, as the C standard only guarantees that a `long` will be as least as long as an `int`.

---

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(__GNUC__)
#define WORD64  unsigned __int64
#else
#define WORD64  unsigned long long
#endif
```

If this is a 32-bit Windows platform and the GNU C compiler is not available, then use the Microsoft-specific datatype for 64-bit words (`unsigned __int64`). Otherwise, use the GNU C datatype (`unsigned long long`).

---

```
// THIRTYTWO_BIT
#endif
```

Every `#if` and `#ifdef` directive must be matched by a corresponding `#endif` to delineate where the conditional section ends. This line ends the `#ifdef THIRTYTWO_BIT` declaration made previously.

---

```
#ifdef EIGHT_BIT

#define WORD unsigned short
#define WORDLENGTH 4

// EIGHT_BIT
#endif
```

If the target processor has a word width of 8 bits, then define a `WORD` to be an `unsigned short`, and define the `WORDLENGTH` to be 4 (again, presumably in bytes).

Comment: "and the GNU C compiler is not available"... it's more a matter of the GNU C compiler not being the one compiling the code... ;-).  Anyway, +1 for a good, patient explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a definition of constants (aka defines) depending on the #define EIGHT_BIT.

If EIGHT_BIT is defined, WORD means unsigned short and WORDLENGTH is 4. Otherwise, WORD is unsigned long and WORDLENGTH is also 4. Additionally, WORD64 will be defined as unsigned long long unless you are on a WIN32 system and not using GCC.

Answer (score 5):

All the "code" does it setup pre-processor symbols for any "live" code that you do have. If a symbol called `EIGHT_BIT` is defined before this code is pre-processed, it sets up `WORD` and `WORDLENGTH` accordingly (though `WORDLENGTH`'s value is suspect), and it will set up the values differently if `EIGHT_BIT` is not already defined.

Comment: +1 for noting that WORDLENGTH of 4 for a WORD that is `unsigned short` is extremely dubious.